# ETbb font package not working (missing TFM & CFG files)

Tags: fonts, missing, font-metrics, cfg

When trying to compile (even the simplest) documents using the ETbb package, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ETbb}
\begin{document}
    Test.
\end{document}
```

I get errors involving missing font metric files:

```
line 3: Font T1/ETbb-TLF/m/n/10=ETbb-Regular-tlf-t1 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \begin{document}
line 3: Font \T1/ETbb-TLF/regular/n/10=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \begin{document}
```

The log also contains the following:

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\⟨username⟩\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
Couldn't open `ETbb-Regular-tlf-.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) […]
Couldn't open `nullfo.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) […]
Process finished with errors
```

In `miktex-makemf.log` there are repeated entries (in this case, referring to virtual font metric files `ETbb-Italic-tlf-swash-t1.vf` and `ETbb-Regular-tlf-t1.vf`) like:

```
INFO  miktex-maketfm - this process (16508) started by 'pdflatex' with command line: miktex-maketfm --verbose ETbb1-Regular-tlf-swash-t1
INFO  miktex-maketfm - installing package fontname triggered by fontname\special.map
[…]
INFO  miktex-maketfm - mpm: extracting files from fontname.tar.lzma...
INFO  miktex-maketfm.core - start process: initexmf --mkmaps
INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose ETbb1-Regular-tlf-swash-t1
INFO  miktex-maketfm.core - start process: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose ETbb1-Regular-tlf-swash-t1
INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -g ETbb1-Regular-tlf-swash-t1 300
INFO  miktex-maketfm.core - start process: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose -g ETbb1-Regular-tlf-swash-t1 300
FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font ETbb1-Regular-tlf-swash-t1.
FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font ETbb1-Regular-tlf-swash-t1.
FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info: 
FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source: 
FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0
INFO  miktex-maketfm - this process (16508) finishes with exit code 1
```

I am using MiKTeX and the problem occurs in both regular and pre-release distributions. Refreshing font map files, reinstalling packages etc. did not help. A few weeks ago, documents using ETbb were still compiling well, so the problem may be caused by some recent updates.

If the problem is not limited to my particular installation, this may indicate that there are packaging errors or conflicts within MiKTeX. Before I fill [a bug report](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues), maybe someone more expert could take a look and confirm that the problem is caused the ETbb package or another component of MiKTeX, and that there are no definite user-side solutions.

Comment: it is a miktex packaging error, all the tfm and other files are missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is now reported on MiKTeX’s [GitHub](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/944).